# How do I get full syntax in sql dump?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a backup of a database, but for versioning purposes, I would like complete insert statements, like this:

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`id`, `type`) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`id`, `type`) VALUES (2, 2);
```

Instead of the default:

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`id`, `type`) VALUES (1, 2), (2, 2);
```

My main reason for doing this is that it will put all the insert values on their own lines instead of on a single line for an entire table.

I tried adding the `--complete-inserts` and `--extended-inserts` in various formats, (one and both at the same time) and so far, I haven't seen any change in the resulting sql file from the mysqldump.

Here is my query, using complete, extended and verbose flags:

```
mysqldump -cev --user=<user> --password=<password> <dbname> > <file_location>/backup.sql
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the option you are looking for:

```
--skip-extended-insert
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure how I missed that option, but that was exactly what I needed.